# Capture number if string contains "X", but limit match (cannot use groups)

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds

I need to extract numbers like `2.268` out of strings that contain the word `output`:

> Approxmiate output size of output: 2.268 kilobytes

But ignore it in strings that don't:

> some entirely different string: 2.268 kilobytes

This regex:

```
(?:output.+?)([\d\.]+)
```

Gives me a match with 1 group, with the group being `2.268` for the target string. But since I'm not using a programming language but rather CloudWatch Log Insights, I need a way to only match the number itself without using groups.

I could use a positive lookbehind `?<=` in order to not consume the string at all, but then I don't know how to throw away `size of output:`  without using `.+`, which positive lookbehind doesn't allow.

Comment: If the value of the capturing group cannot be extracted separately, and your environment does not support lookbehinds, you are stuck.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew - while the first part is correct, I don't know why my question implied that my environment doesn't support lookbehinds.

Comment: If lookbehinds work for you, why not use `(?<=output.+)\d[\d.]*`? See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/rJ0PD9/1).

Comment: Also, PCRE supports `output.+\K\d[\d.]*`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew OK I was pretty sure I tried that and it matched the whole string with a group inside which was problematic. This one should work, can you add it as an answer please?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I know why it didn't work, you're using the ECMAScript version while I was using PCRE which gives "A quantifier inside a lookbehind makes it non-fixed width" when using positive-lookbehinds with a `+`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are using PCRE, you can use

```php
output.*?\K\d[\d.]*
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/rJ0PD9/2). This matches

- `output` - a fixed string
- `.*?` - any zero or more chars other than line break chars, as few as possible
- `\K` - match reset operator that removes all text matched so far from the overall match memory buffer
- `\d` - a digit
- `[\d.]*` - zero or more digits or periods.

Answer (score 3):

With your shown samples, please try following regex.

```
output:\D+\K\d(?:\.\d+)?
```

[Online demo for above regex](https://regex101.com/r/A6tXHo/1)

***Explanation:*** Adding detailed explanation for above.

```
output:\D+    ##Matching output colon followed by non-digits(1 or more occurrences)
\K            ##\K to forget previous matched values to make sure we get only further matched values in this expression.
\d(?:\.\d+)?  ##Matching digit followed by optional dot digits.
```